# Regex matching comma-separated list of values, trailing comma not allowed

Tags: regular-expression

I want to match:

1. aaa
2. aaa,bbb
3. aaa,bbb,ccc

But **not** a list with a trailing comma. My [current](https://regex101.com/r/rZYPWT/1) regex:

```
(\w{3},?)+
```

also matches lists with trailing commas (`aaa,bbb,`). I was thinking I could also [do](https://regex101.com/r/AaSxYl/1):

```
(\w{3})(,\w{3})*
```

but that is rather ugly. My real regex is not matching 3-letter-words, but something bigger, and repeating the regex is ugly. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you need tthe capturing group?

Comment: Is it full line matching?

Comment: What you have is a decent solution to the problem. If you have a much bigger problem, state that

Comment: Capturing group is not needed. Yes full line matching. And repeating the BIG regex twice does not sound decent ;)

Comment: I think a regex as simple as:  [^,]$  answers the question as posted. If it doesn't what information would explain why it's not sufficient?

Comment: Sh*t, that is it, of course. Can you put it as an answer Hkoof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give a name to your **big** regex in PCRE like:

```
(?<big>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Everything after the `?<name>` will be recorded with the name given.
Called [Regular Expression Subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html)

So, repeats (`?&name`) become easy:

```
^(?<big>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(,(?&big))*$
```

[Test it Online](https://regex101.com/r/E4kyvA/1)

So, matching an IP, for example, becomes simpler:

```
^(?<ip>25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(.(?&ip)){3}$
```

[Test it OnLine](https://regex101.com/r/3lZOUw/1).

Use it with grep as:

```
grep -P '^(?<ip>25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(.(?&ip)){3}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `perl` or PCRE regexps, you can avoid repetition by using things like `(?1)` to refer to the regexp in the first capture group:

```
grep -Px '(?:(\w{3}),)*(?1)'
```

Which would match on any non-empty comma separated list of 3 character words. Change to:

```
grep -Px '(?:(?:(\w{3}),)*(?1))?'
```

To allow an empty list.

Comment: [Regular Expression Subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) Seem to be useful also.

Answer (score 0):

Please use - `^((([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,45},){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,45})$`

Here, I have set max word size to 45, as longest word in English is 45 characters, can be changed as per requirement

Answer (score -1):

The regex as simple as: `[^,]$` answers the question.

Thanks to @Hkoof for their comment!

Comment: It answers the question in that it matches on those 3 samples and not on anything that ends in `,` but it would also match anything that ends in a character other than `,` like `aaaa` or `a,,,,b`... What about your _big regexp_?